# How is it possible that Session is null in the AuthorizeAttribute.AuthorizeCore method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-migration

I have a custom attribute class which inherits from `AuthorizeAttribute`. Sometimes the parameter `httpContext.Session` is null. How is this possible? The Session supposed to be alive as long as I am logged/active, right? I am not brwosing for 20 minutes or longer, in fact I am just browsing for 0-2 minutes and sometimes the Session property is null.

We have this bug since we are switched from MVC 2 (.NET 3.5) to MVC 4.5 (.Net 4.5) Is it possible that this is the cause of the problems?

How can I solve this?

Comment: Place a conditional breakpoint and find out when/how it is called.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I did place a conditional breakpoint and I don't have a call stack. It just says '[External Code]' and on top of that the line where the breakpoint is.

Comment: And what can you learn from the context? Esp. the requested target.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't know what you precisely mean, but in the HttpContext.Current is the Session null

Answer (score 1):

> How is this possible?

This could happen if you have disabled session state. In order to disable session state you could have the following in your web.config:

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

or you could have decorated your controller/base controller/action with the `[SessionState]` attribute:

```
[SessionState(SessionStateBehavior.Disabled)]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't have `sessionState mode="Off"` Everything is set to "InProc". I also don't have a SessionState attribute

Answer (score 1):

This could be a caching issue. Try overriding:

```
OnCacheAuthorization
```

in the filter.
Or remove:

```
OutputCache
```

attributes from actions in the controller.

Comment: A demo on how to override it and what this will acieve, would be handy here. How does this work? When you return `HttpValidationStatus.Invalid` from `OnCacheAuthorization`, then `AuthorizeCore` is not called at all?

Comment: OK. I found out : Search for `OnCacheAuthorization(HttpContextBase httpContext)` here: https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs . Cheers! :)

Comment: So, if one had to validate the session for a cached action, how would he do it? The session object is not initialized inside `OnCacheAuthorization`. My case did not require that, but what if it did? Isn't that possible? :o

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a little to far back for me to remember the details. I hope you solve you problem.

Comment: I need to do exactly that @user2173353

Comment: @RomaineCarter I think that the easiest fix would be to implement some caching mechanism by yourself inside the action.